# R Comparison of Rows of a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix which looks like this

```
aaa = matrix(c(1,1,7,9,2,5,8,9,1,2,3,7),nrow=3,ncol=4)
```

Now I need to find for each row the number(s) which are different from the previous row (irrespective of the ordering in the row). So for example the different numbers from row 1 and 2 would be 8 and 3. The output must be a list. How would the code need to be for such an exercise?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: may be `lapply(1:(nrow(aaa)-1), function(i) {a1 <- rbind(aaa[i,], aaa[i+1,]); unique(a1[!a1 %in%intersect(a1[1,], a1[2,])])})`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that does this, based on the combination of two `setdiff()` operations:

```
foo <- function(x, y)c(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
foo(aaa[1, ], aaa[2, ])

[1] 8 3
```

Applied on your matrix:

```
lapply(1:(nrow(aaa)-1), function(i)foo(aaa[i, ], aaa[i+1, ]))

[[1]]
[1] 8 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 9 3 7 5
```

Answer (score 1):

An lapply solution similar to akrun but using `union` and `setdiff`:

```
lapply(1:(nrow(aaa)-1), function(x) {union(setdiff(aaa[x,], aaa[x+1,]), setdiff(aaa[x+1,], aaa[x,]))})

[[1]]
[1] 8 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 9 3 7 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the set difference between the union and the intersection of the values of two consecutive rows. Try this:

```
    ret<-vector("list",nrow(aaa)-1)
    for (i in 1:length(ret)) ret[[i]]<-setdiff(union(aaa[i,],aaa[i+1,]),intersect(aaa[i,],aaa[i+1,]))
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
fun1 <- function(mat){
Pdat <- as.data.frame(t(mat[-nrow(mat),]))
Cdat <- as.data.frame(t(mat[-1,]))
foo <- function(x,y) {z <- c(x,y)
                  unique(z[!z %in% intersect(x,y)])} 
setNames(Map(foo, Pdat, Cdat), NULL)
 }       


 fun1(aaa)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 8 3

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 2 9 3 7 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a=1; b=2
ll = list()
llnum = 1
while(TRUE) {
    ll[[llnum]]=unique(aaa[a,!(aaa[a,] %in% aaa[b,])])
    ll[[llnum+1]]=unique(aaa[b,!(aaa[b,] %in% aaa[a,])])
    llnum = llnum+2
    a=a+1; b=b+1;
    if(b>nrow(aaa)) break;
}

ll
[[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 9 3

[[4]]
[1] 7 5
```